# Multi object Communication between instances in J groups

Tags: jgroups

I have a program which needs to communicate itself under Multi Instances. It like if a instance has loaded a object from DB, other instances would jus use them.

The getState and setState in J-groups implementing Receiver supports only one object to communicate..
Is there s way to communicate between the Instances

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the `send()` method of the `Channel` class does that.  You can send your message to every nodes of the cluster or just a specific node.